# Error: ast_sockaddr_resolve: getaddrinfo("a783543c-1911-44c4-9ba1-52114bbdccb4.local", "(null)", ...): Name or service not known

Tags: webrtc, asterisk, sip, jssip

We connect JsSip to Astersik and long time all worked perfect.
After than unexpectedly voice dissapear without any reason. 
We see in astersik log next message

```
ast_sockaddr_resolve: getaddrinfo("a783543c-1911-44c4-9ba1-52114bbdccb4.local", "(null)", ...): Name or service not known
```

I read JsSip documetation. In version 1.0 was parameter [hack_ip_in_contact](https://jssip.net/documentation/3.0.x/api/ua_configuration_parameters/#hack_ip_in_contact)
Now instead of it exist parameter `contact_uri`.
I set `contact_uri` but nothing changes.

We tried to add `a783543c-1911-44c4-9ba1-52114bbdccb4.local` in `/etc/hosts`
It was very strange but it worked until reconnect JsSip. After re conect Jssip this uid changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how fix it in JsSip but we made hack for resolve this problem.
We use **dnsmasq** and forward all addresses like **XXX.local** to **localhost**.